# can't create telegram bot using telegraf package

Tags: node.js, telegram, telegram-bot, telegraf.js

I'm trying to create a telegram bot using [telegraf](https://www.npmjs.com/package/telegraf)

I read its documentation and I just wanted to start coding using their own examples

this is the example provided in documentation:

```js
const { Telegraf } = require('telegraf')

const bot = new Telegraf(process.env.BOT_TOKEN)
bot.start((ctx) => ctx.reply('Welcome'))
bot.help((ctx) => ctx.reply('Send me a sticker'))
bot.on('sticker', (ctx) => ctx.reply(''))
bot.hears('hi', (ctx) => ctx.reply('Hey there'))
bot.launch()

// Enable graceful stop
process.once('SIGINT', () => bot.stop('SIGINT'))
process.once('SIGTERM', () => bot.stop('SIGTERM'))
```

when i try to run the code,i get the following error:

> TypeError: Object.fromEntries is not a function
> [image: error screenshot]

PS: I have got my `BOT_TOKEN` from *BotFather* and placed it in the .env

thanks in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

there are some issues with the new version of telegraf.

i currently use version 3.38.0 and it works just fine.

Comment: `npm i telegraf@3.38.0`

Answer (score 3):

It seems you are using old version of node.js that do not support Object.fromEntries

Just update it to at least 12 version

Answer (score 1):

Which version of telegraf are you using?

They updated it recently, still some bugs are not cleared. Remove telegraf, and install 3.38th version, and try to launch again. If won't work, then something is wrong with your configuration.

Comment: thanks pal
its working after installing 3.38.0 version

Comment: Welcome! 

You can follow their official telegram channels, where the community discusses everything related to telegraf.

Comment: @TigranPetrosyan can you provide a link to their telegram handles...